# Is there any advantage using high-order functions (filter, map, fold) instead of pattern matching in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, higher-order-functions, fold

I have some code in Haskell that is using pattern matching. However, I think that I can use folds and filters. For me this would be more readable, but I want to know it there is any advantage in terms of complexity.

Comment: In terms of time complexity? If you do the pattern matching efficiently, no.

Comment: Frequently, `filter`, etc. however work a bit more efficient, due to for example list fusion, etc. But an effective implementation will typically yield a comparable result.

Answer (score 5):

The main reason to use higher-order functions instead of pattern matching and manual recursion is that it makes your code more concise and way easier to read.

Once you get the hang of them, you'll find that reading source code suddenly became way easier as those functions are amongst the most popular in all of Haskell.

It's also considered a good practice, and many people appreciate that you abstract your code.